# Campo file com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou criando um upload através de um modal dessa forma:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header btn-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ALTERAR FOTO</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post" id="form-upload" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <label for="email">Tamanho da imagem: 1170 x 300</label>
               <div class="md-group-add-on">
                <span class="md-add-on-file">
                    <button class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Foto</button>
                </span>
            <div class="md-input-file">
                <input type="file" id="submit" name="FotoCapa" class=""/>
                <input type="text" class="md-form-control md-form-file">
                <label class="md-label-file"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
              <div id="success"></div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Com Jquery, estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', $('#fotoCapa').prop('files')[0]);
      $.ajax({
          url: 'alterar-foto-capa.php',
          data: formData,
          type: 'post',
          success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
              if(response){    
                 $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>A foto foi alterada com sucesso!</div>");
                  $('#fotoCapa').val('');
              }else{
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + response + "</div>");
             }
          },
          processData: false,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false
      });
   });        
});          
</script>
```

O problema é que quando tento pegar o valor com PHP:

```
$foto = $_FILES["FotoCapa"]['name'];
echo json_encode($foto);
```

No console aparece o seguinte erro:

```
(index):596 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):596)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
```

Quando altero essa linha:

```
formData.append('image', $('#fotoCapa').prop('files'));
```

O console retorna null.

Comment: O correto não seria `$foto = $_FILES['image']['name'];`?

Comment: Olá Ricardo. Na verdade o "FotoCapa" é o nome do campo, com isso `$_FILES["FotoCapa"]['name']` está correto. O problema está no Jquery mesmo.

Comment: talvez setar as propriedades `contentType: false` e `processData: false` na chamada `Ajax` resolvam

Comment: Não vai dar certo, o id não é `fotoCapa`. Veja: `id="submit" name="FotoCapa"`

Comment: No PHP também está errado, o nome do campo tem quer ser `image`, ou você troca na hora de dar o `append` no ´FormData´

Comment: Olá Denis. Fiz as alterações, `<input type="file" id="fotoCapa" name="FotoCapa" class=""/>`e `formData.append('FotoCapa', $('#fotoCapa').prop('files')[0]);`, porém agora retorna null.

Comment: Achei o erro, você executa a função no evento de `click`, o arquivo só existe após o evento `change`

Comment: A propósito Ricardo. Você tinha razão sobre o nome da variável global. Era  `$foto = $_FILES['image']['name'];` conforme você disse. Me desculpe por isso ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está na hora em que você invoca a função, se chamá-la no evento `click`, o arquivo ainda não existe, tanto que a janela de seleção de arquivos do navegador nem chega a abrir, você tem que chamá-la no evento `change`, quado a janela já foi aberta e o arquivo foi selecionado pelo usuário.

Seu código com as alterações:

```js
$(function(){
    $('#submit').change(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert($('#submit').prop('files')[0].name)
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('image', $('#submit').prop('files')[0]);
      $.ajax({
          url: 'alterar-foto-capa.php',
          data: formData,
          type: 'post',
          success: function(response){
             console.log(response);
              if(response){    
                 $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>A foto foi alterada com sucesso!</div>");
                  $('#fotoCapa').val('');
              }else{
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>" + response + "</div>");
             }
          },
          processData: false,
          cache: false,
          contentType: false
      });
   });        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header btn-primary">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ALTERAR FOTO</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post" id="form-upload" novalidate enctype="multipart/form-data">
               <label for="email">Tamanho da imagem: 1170 x 300</label>
               <div class="md-group-add-on">
                <span class="md-add-on-file">
                    <button class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">Foto</button>
                </span>
            <div class="md-input-file">
                <input type="file" id="submit" name="FotoCapa" class=""/>
                <input type="text" class="md-form-control md-form-file">
                <label class="md-label-file"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
              <div id="success"></div>
          </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Quando for resgatar via PHP, vai ter que utilizar o mesmo nome que usou em `formData.append()`

Comment: Bingo Denis. Funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado!